# PHP namespaces and inheritence

Tags: php, inheritance, namespaces

I want to extend standard `PDO` class. So i have:

```
namespace Example;

class NewPDO extends PDO {}
```

but i get the following error :

**Fatal error:** Class 'Example\PDO' not found in **/home/hdocs/lab/index.php** on line **4**

I know that's because `PDO` class is not within `Example` namespace.
how can i solve that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PDO` is in global namespace, you should add `\` before it.

```
namespace Example;

class NewPDO extends \PDO {}
```